# "laying it out there"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, idioms, north-american-english

"The child is not mine. I found out through one of her friends."

"Why hasn't she told you?"

"I don't know. I guess she just felt more comfortable not **laying it out there**."

"You must be angry."

"I am."

Is the third sentence perfectly natural in American English? Can "laying it out there" mean to mention something to someone?

Comment: Probably more idiomatic is "laying your cards on the table".  But there are a number of variants, each with its own connotations.

Answer (score 1):

To "lay it out" in this instance means to speak in all honesty, to openly admit, to freely share information. The urban dictionary [shows a good ratio](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lay%20it%20out) of confirmatory votes on this (albeit the absolute numbers are low, 14:0) with "lay it out" defined as **to tell the truth** or **to be honest**.

It's important to be wary of urbandict definitions but a little random googling confirms this use and suggests it being American everyday slang, for instance: "But most of the time we don’t care about **laying it out with integrity** unless it’s our heart that’s on the line. When it suits us, many of us will tell a whole lie to someone and then blame them for getting hurt when the truth comes out in the end." (taken from someone's [personal twitter status](https://twitter.com/ilove_vonnie/status/984603027721080833) apparently concerned with truth-telling, if you really need to check)

American users may be more resourceful as to how common this semantic usage is. In most other instances, "lay it out" when denoting a speech act means just to explain clearly, to explicate in detail.

Comment: If you want to show usage "ratios" use Google nGrams. Urban Dictionary is not a reliable source.